# Binding to static property in static class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, static

I have a problem with binding values from static properties from static class.

My class:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    public static class MySettings
    {
        public static Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
        public static Color FontColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Page ...
       xmlns:colors="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Data"
      ...>
 ...
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Text"
        Background="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.BackgroundColor}}"
        Foreground="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.FontColor}}"
        BorderBrush="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.FontColor}}"/>
```

and when I run this code Background is set OK but the rest remains unchanged..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem is that your source properties are of a [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type and destination properties are [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can create [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using your color like so:

```
<Button Content="Text">
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.BackgroundColor}}"/>
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.FontColor}}"/>
    </Button.Foreground>
    <Button.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MySettings.FontColor}}"/>
    </Button.BorderBrush>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use `static` properties... you can declare a class using the `Singleton` pattern, so there can only be one instance, just *like* a `static` class. Just use normal `public` CLR properties in this class... something like this (but with properties):

```
public class StateManager
{
    private static StateManager instance;
    
    private StateManager() { }

    public static StateManager Instance
    {
        get { return instance ?? (instance = new StateManager()); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then only reference it from a base view model using the `Instance` property like this:

```
public StateManager StateManager
{
    get { return StateManager.Instance; }
}
```

Then you can access the properties in the UI simply, like this::

```
<Ribbon:RibbonCheckBox Grid.Row="1" Label="Audit fields" 
    IsChecked="{Binding StateManager.AreAuditFieldsVisible}" ... />
<Ribbon:RibbonCheckBox Grid.Row="2" Label="ISRCs on results" 
    IsChecked="{Binding StateManager.AreIsrcsVisibleOnSearchResults}" ... />
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was searching for - i.e. the use of a regular (non-static) class in a binding.  Why is it that you don't need to specify `"Source={...` in the `Binding` markup?

Comment: What about If you need this instance in App.xaml code behind ? In eed to set static variable there, in OnStartup event.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82, You can use it wherever you like. It's just a class and will be initialised upon it's first use.