# Bind to static property of static class

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm searching for a way to bind the `ItemsSource` of a `GridView` to the **static property** of a **static class**.

Since the class is **static** I can't set the `(Binding).Source` to an instance of the class and setting it to the property doesn't work.

**Unfortunately the XAML markup extensions `x:Static` doesn't work for Windows Apps so that's not an option either.**

Marking this bold since people obviously **DO NOT** understand that the WPF answer **DOES NOT** work in Windows Runtime. How about reading the question before marking it as duplicate...

Comment: windows-runtime is not wpf
as I already said x:Static does not work for windows-runtime apps

Comment: Please ask a new question, and link it here please so I can provide an answer. I was able to get this working without any issue.
    public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<string> StaticStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

        private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                StaticClass.StaticStrings.Add("static" + i.ToString());
            }
            this.DataContext = StaticClass.StaticStrings;
        }

Comment: @BryanStump Feel free to answer now. I found a way to do it programmatically by using an instance described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21048720/3314225). But the only way I found to use the class in XAML was by adding an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with no problems.

```
public static class StaticClass 
{ 
    public static ObservableCollection<string> StaticStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>(); 
} 

private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    { 
        StaticClass.StaticStrings.Add("static" + i.ToString()); 
    } 
    this.DataContext = StaticClass.StaticStrings; 
}
```