# How to Call Variable from Class in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a class called ClsGlobVar.vb Where I define a solid brush color.  These colors will be used to set colors based on conditions and user preferences.

Inside the class I define my colors as one example.

```
Public Shared ColorHighlight = New SolidColorBrush(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFF48B2A"))
```

I want to use that variable to set the colors in my application.xaml file.  Something like:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColHighlight" Color="{Binding Path=clsGlobVar.ColorHighlight}"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding to static property in static class in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048536/binding-to-static-property-in-static-class-in-wpf)

Comment: No, but that could be because I don't understand the C# very well and am having trouble following what's trying to be done

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a duplicate of [Binding to static property in static class in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048536/binding-to-static-property-in-static-class-in-wpf), but that's in C#, so I'll answer here in VB.NET.

First, `ColorHighlight` needs to be a property, rather than a field. Binding generally doesn't work with fields.

```
Public Shared Property ColorHighlight As New SolidColorBrush(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFF48B2A"))
```

`Shared` in VB.NET is basically equivilent to `static` in C#. WPF also seems to use the name `static`, because the markup expention used to reference `Shared` members is [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension). In your example, you could use it like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColHighlight" Color="{x:Static local:clsGlobVar.ColorHighlight}"/>
```

Notice I added `local:`. This is the default prefix the for [XAML namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) of your own project.

---

It should be noted that this approach of binding to a `Shared` property doesn't support change notification. If the value of `ColorHighlight` changes at runtime, the `SolidColorBrush` will not update.

If you need change notification, I would suggest implementing the "singleton pattern". This is also suggested in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21048720/5086631) from the same question linked above. A class created using the singleton pattern can also implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) and so provide change notifications, unlike `Shared` classes/properties.